# Laravel 5.8 / Mysql: Cannot delete or update a parent row a foreign key constraint fails

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, foreign-keys

I am trying to setup my tables in my MySQL database and and I am currently creating migration files using Laravel 5.8. When I run a fresh migration with

> php artisan migrate

all the migrations run smoothly and my foreign key is correctly added to my table

[image: https://i.imgur.com/HIlR4i9.png]

However when I want to update my database with

> php artisan migrate:refresh

I run into this error

> Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : **SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1451 Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (SQL: drop table if exists `services`)**

What I've tried so far:

Splitting my foreign keys in different migration files so that they come after my tables that doesn't have foreign keys in them

File architecture in visual studio code

[image: File Architecture]

adding **->onDelete('cascade')** on each foreign key in my up() functions (code below)

My **Services** migration file

```
class CreateServicesTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('services', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->text('description');
            $table->integer('price');
            $table->boolean('multiple_times');
            $table->boolean('location');
            $table->integer('animal_type_id')->unsigned();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('services');
    }
}
```

My **AnimalType** foreign key

```
class ForeignKeyAnimalTypeServices extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('services', function($table){
            $table->foreign('animal_type_id')->references('id')->on('animal_types')->onDelete('cascade');
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('services', function(Blueprint $table){
            $table->dropForeign(['animal_type_id']);
        });
    }
}
```

My **Service** model

```
class Service extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'services';
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'description', 'price', 'multiple_times', 'location'
    ];

    public function animalType()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\AnimalType');
    }
}
```

Although my migrations are created, I can't refresh my migrations if I need to (or seed my table). I want to be able to refresh my files without getting this error.
I am still pretty new to programming, my apologies if there is missing information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In migration `Class ForeignKeyAnimalTypeServices`

Try:

```
public function down()
    {
        Schema::disableForeignKeyConstraints();
        Schema::table('services', function(Blueprint $table){
            $table->dropForeign(['animal_type_id']);
        });

        Schema::dropIfExists('services');
        Schema::enableForeignKeyConstraints();

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot drop a foreign key i was forced to drop all the database and recreate it, although this could help you:

```
ALTER TABLE table drop FOREIGN KEY transaction_client_id_foreign;
```